# Админка, сайт и пути к файлам

Tags: php, пути, чпу

Сайт пишется с использованием ЧПУ. Обязательно ли код админки должен находится на одном уровне вложенности, что и сам сайт? Ну, то есть чтобы доступ к файлам имел одинаковый вид, например : ../..images/image1.jpg.

Дело в том, что я написал уже более половины кода и с ужасом увидел, что картинки стали недоступны для основного кода, потому что ЧПУ сайта имеет на один уровень больше чем ЧПУ админки, поэтому путь "../../images/image1.jpg" ведет в разные места (((

Если кто-нибудь хоть что-то понял, подскажите.

Comment: вообще относительные пути старайтесь не использовать. 


*/me злорадствует над теми параноиками что говорят "надо админку отдельно разрабатывать, и таблицу отдельно..."*

Comment: @eicto, привет. Вся проблема в том, что использую tinymce, при этом этот плагин сам преобразует пути к файлам в относительные, я так и не смог найти в десятках этих скриптов, как  где формируются эти пути. При вставке картинки ее путь передается в "../и т.д.", а мне нужно "/../". Придется писать говнокод, чтобы обмануть этот плагин.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RewriteBase в htaccess если сайт не в корне
если в корне почему был не использовать / в начале всех файлов? :)

Comment: все в корне и все нормально, однако я пока делал админку, забыл, что к ЧПУ основной страницы еще и добавляется что-то типа языка - /ru/ или /en/, что и увеличивает уровень вложенности

Comment: я имею ввиду, что если сайт будет весь лежать в www.site.com/ то, просто делайте изначалсь все картинки/файлы и остальную статику типа
<img src="/image/path/image.jpg" /> и в админке тоже ибо такой конструкцией "из админки" файлы будут искаться в корне сайта.

Comment: Супер! Я об этом подзабыл, потому что пути к картинкам проставляются сами с помощью TinyMCE, ща все сделаем.Спасибо!

Comment: Да не за что) Все гениальное -- просто :)

Answer (score 0):

Ну вот так не делает никто. Есть клёвая функция realpath()
Вот нужно её юзать.

В корне юзаем вот так

```
$path = realpath("./") . "images/1.jpeg"
```

В админке

```
$path = realpath("../") . "images/1.jpeg"
```

Comment: дело в том, что созданный в админке контент записывается в БД, т.е. путь к картинкам имеет один вид как для админки, так и для самого сайта.

Comment: а причем тут контент, созданный в админке?? в первоначальном вопросе такого не написано... но все равно, используйте абсолютный путь. В данном случае будет проще.